# HasFocus vs IsActive

Tags: wxwidgets

How can a Frame be "Active" but not have "Focus"?
According tot he Windows documentation, AFAICT, a window gains focus when it becomes active, so why are there two variables and how can one be True without the other also being True?

Answer (score 2):

Focus may (and most often does) belong to a child of the active top-level window. Or, if you prefer, the active window is the top level parent of the focused window.

Comment: Does this mean that a child window cannot ever be active?

Comment: Well, `IsActive()` is a member of `wxTopLevelWindow` and not `wxWindow`, so you can't even ask if a child window is active. I guess this could be considered as meaning that it can never be active...

Answer (score 1):

Any wxTopLevelWindow-derived (wxFrame, wxDialog, and their derives) has the method `IsActive()`. The wx docs say:

> Returns true if this window is currently active, i.e. if the user is
>   currently working with it.

"*working with it*" means the user is resizing/moving it, or mouse-clicking in a tool bar, or typing in a control.

`HasFocus()` makes the focused window to accept **keyboard** input (even it isn't a text-control).

Notice the slight difference between "working with it" and "accept keyboard input".

And there's another query: `IsEnabled()`, for user input, which is not the same as "user action".